# itext ConvertToPdf "Could not instantiate TagWorker-class" error on server, but not when debugging

Tags: c#, itext7, html2pdf

I'm using the itext7.pdfhtml (2.1.2) Nuget, and I've been able to successfully create a pdf file with my html by using HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf while debugging. The web application is now installed at the client's server, but when the method is called, I'm getting an error, and can't seem to find any documentation on that error.

"Could not instantiate TagWorker-class iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Tags.HtmlTagWorker for tag html."

I'm really at a lost, and don't know what this error means, or how to fix it. Any leads would be appreciated. Let me know if you need additional information (This is one of the first time that I post here). The code is very straight forward.

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(strHtml, new FileStream(receivingViewModel.ReceivingPDFPath + @"\" + receiving.ReceiptNumber + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Thanks!

Pier-Luc

Comment: For now, I'm going to try alternatives like IronPdf, and wkhtmtopdf to see if they're as good.

Comment: Please attach complete log output. pdfHTML should have logged root cause of that error as well.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this ? I'm struggling with the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi lailalta, I think that the main issue was that it's not compatible with .NET Core yet. So what I had to do was create a web service with .NET Framework, and make a call there when I needed to execute that function.

Comment: Actually I can create a .NET Core 2.1 Console project that runs perfectly fine.  If I push the identical code up to an Azure function using .NETCore 2.1 I get the exact error above.